# Get Image ID from touchstart event javascript

Tags: javascript, image, touchstart

I am working on an app in which i have 5 images and i want to get the Id of the image when touchstart event begins because i want to move those images to a certain position. I am using javascript.

Comment: Have you tried `event.target`?

Comment: Yes event.target.id it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, and provided that you have touchstart event bound to image

```
$('img').bind('touchstart', function() {
    var imageId = this.id;    
});
```